# Identify when a time series reaches certain value

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I have been using SARIMA to forecast a time series as it has trend and seasonality. Is it possible to identify when the time series would reach a certain value? For example when would the time series reach a value of 100 considering trend and seasonality.

Comment: Would there be something wrong with just keep forecasting into the future?

Comment: You can consider a loop to run through values from 1 till the index where the prediction value reaches 100.